# Windows Batch: Call function for each path in delimited string

Tags: batch-file

I have a variable that contains the following:

```
"pdfList=D:\BundleManager\AssetPackageManager.unity;D:\BundleManager\AssetPackageManager.unity\.vs\AssetPackageManager.unity;D:\Crafting\CraftingExample.unity;D:\ResMan\FFResManExample.Unity;"
```

And I want to call a function for each of those paths separated by ; The code I currently have is

```
for /F "delims=;" %%a in ("%pdfList%") do (@echo %%a)
```

But this is just echoing the following

```
D:\BundleManager\AssetPackageManager.unity
```

I've tried setting `tokens=*` as an option but this just echos the value of pdfList complete with ; still present. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try `for %%a in ("%pdfList:;=";"%") do (@echo %%~a)`

Comment: Yeah that looks like it works, thanks. If you want to add that as an answer instead of a comment and explain whats going on I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: Shorter: `echo %pdflist:;=&echo/%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `for /F` loops line-by-line, rather than token-by-token.  A better solution is to use `for` without any switches.  `for` will tokenize data, splitting on unquoted spaces, commas, semicolons, and tabs.

To prevent pathnames containing spaces or commas from being truncated, you can massage the data and replace all semicolons with `";"` using batch variable substring substitution, then surround the whole thing in quotation marks.  [See this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace) for full details on substring replacements.

So basically,

```
a;b c;d e;f
```

becomes

```
a";"b c";"d e";"f
```

becomes

```
"a";"b c";"d e";"f"
```

which is easily tokenized, and spaces are preserved.  Apply this principle to your code above:

```
@echo off & setlocal

set "pdfList=D:\BundleManager\AssetPackageManager.unity;D:\BundleManager\AssetPackageManager.unity\.vs\AssetPackageManager.unity;D:\Crafting\CraftingExample.unity;D:\ResMan\FFResManExample.Unity"

for %%a in ("%pdfList:;=";"%") do echo(%%~a
```

The output is now:

> D:\BundleManager\AssetPackageManager.unity
>   D:\BundleManager\AssetPackageManager.unity.vs\AssetPackageManager.unity
>   D:\Crafting\CraftingExample.unity
>   D:\ResMan\FFResManExample.Unity

Comment: Thanks very much for that :)

Comment: @RealWorld Glad I could help!